# How to install Norwegian language pack?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to install Norwegian language pack into my WordPress website, 
I am using multi-site WordPress so please guide me how can i do this.

url=https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/nb/default/wp-plugins/buddypress

Answer (score 0):

## Installing WordPress in Your Language

**WordPress v4.0 and above**

Change the language in the admin settings screen. Settings > General > Site Language.

**WordPress v3.9.2 and below:**
Change the WPLANG in your wp-config.php:

*[Norsk (Nynorsk):](https://nn.wordpress.org/)*

```
define ('WPLANG', 'nn_NOR');
```

or
 *[Norsk (Bokmål)](https://nb.wordpress.org/):*

```
define ('WPLANG', 'nb_NOR');
```

**Multi-Site Installations**

If you have a [site network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) (WordPress multisite), the language is set on a per-blog basis through the "Site language" option in the Settings > General subpanel. 
**All can be read at the official documentation at [wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language)**

Comment: Thanks for reply

this one i try it it working on my WordPress admin panel but i want to my website theme and WordPress content display in Norwegian language into front-page,or all pages,all posts content.